# How to test (and accept) that a coefficient in a linear regression model equals zero

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, equivalence

I understand that in a linear regression model like:

$y_i = b_0 + b_1  x_i  + \epsilon_i$

I can have a null and an alternative hypothesis:

$H_0: b_1 = 0$ and $H_1: b_1 \neq 0$.

And then I can reject $H_0$ or fail to reject $H_0$. But what if I want to accept that $b_1 = 0$?

Comment: Look into equivalence testing.

Comment: You can't *show* that it's 0, since it can be arbitrarily close to zero while being unequal to it. e.g. if $b_1 = 0.0000001$ then $b_1\neq 0$ - and you'd ideally reject that point null, yet with reasonable values for and moderate sample size (and for the disposition of the $x$'s I guess), you can't. Peter's suggestion to consider equivalence testing is a good one (but it's showing something a bit different from what you're asking).

Comment: Thanks @PeterFlom, equivalence testing is what I was looking for. If you write it as an answer I will gladly accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look into equivalence testing.  See [this search](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=equivalence%20testing) for lots of threads. Also see [Esteban & Nowacki](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3019319/)

Answer (score 3):

You cannot. "Accept that $b_1=0$" is the same as "reject that $b_1\ne 0$".  But on what basis you could do this?  No matter how many observations you have, you cannot distinguish between 0 and sufficiently small value of $b_1$.  You can only accept that $|b_1|<\epsilon$  (the smaller $\epsilon$ the more observations you need).

Comment: I agree with that. But that is from the perspective of significance testing. I was looking for a technique specifically designed to test the hypothesis of whether two groups are equal (or a coefficient is zero).

Comment: As user31264 and also glen_b said: You can't. Equivalence tests are only able to show that a parameter is *close* to a certain value but not that it has exactly this value.